# Laravel - Get relationship without Route Model Binding (w/o parameter)

Tags: laravel, routes, url-routing

I have relationship tables where one student may have many subjects. In home page `(/)`, I want to display data from relationship **without** any route parameters.

**Student Model**

```
class Student extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'class', 'subjects'];
  public function all_marks()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Marks::class, 'student_id');
  }
}
```

**Marks Model**

```
class Marks extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = ['name', 'student_id', 'subjects', 'marks'];
  public function marks()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'student_id');
  }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', 'Controller@home')->name('home_page');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function home()
  {
    $students = Student::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
    $minimum_marks = Student::with(['marks'])->where(['student_id'=>$students->id])->min('marks');
    return view ('home', compact('students', 'minimum_marks'));  
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($studens as $student)
 Name: {{ $student->name}}
 Min. marks: {{ $minimum_marks }}
@endforeach
```

Here I got

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

I know I need to have route as

**`Route::get('/{$id}', 'Controller@home')->name('home_page');`** and change function to `public function home($id)`.

But I want to display these on `domain.com` home page not on `domain.com/1`

I heard of Explicit routing, but don't know much.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the property `id` from a collection here

```
->where(['student_id'=>$students->id])
```

That property exists on a single instance of the model and you are trying to call it on a collection of models,so it does not exist.